# Comparing two mysql recordsets using php

Tags: php, mysql, compare, recordset

I need to compare two mysql recordsets using php

Comparing a record in the first recordset is present in the second and returns a true value, or a false if its not present.

The problem is once a do a single pass of the recordset it doesn't return to the beginning so i can compare the the remaining records of recordset1 to it.

The code i'm using is:

```
*mysql_select_db($database_db, $db);

$query_rec_teams = "SELECT tbl_items.* FROM tbl_items;";
$rec_items = mysql_query($query_rec_items, $db) or die(mysql_error());

$row_rec_items = mysql_fetch_assoc($rec_items);
$totalRows_rec_items = mysql_num_rows($rec_items);

$query_rec_itemsLeft = "(SELECT tbl_itemsleft.* FROM tbl_itemsLeft";
$rec_itemsLeft = mysql_query($query_rec_itemsLeft, $db) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rec_itemsLeft = mysql_fetch_assoc($rec_itemsLeft);
$totalRows_rec_itemsLeft = mysql_num_rows($rec_itemsLeft);

//iterate first recordset, populate variables
do{ 
    $itemPresent=0;
    $item=$row_rec_item['ItemID'];
    //iterate second recordset and compare item variable with itemID fields in recordset, if exist echo true, else echo false
    do { 
            if ($row_rec_itemsLeft(['ItemID'] == $item){
                itemPresent=1;
            }
            else{
                itemPresent=0;
            }
        echo itemPresent;
    } while ($row_rec_itemsLeft = mysql_fetch_assoc($rec_itemsLeft));

} while ($row_rec_items = mysql_fetch_assoc($rec_items));

mysql_free_result($rec_itemsLeft);
mysql_free_result($rec_items);
?>*
```

would it be easier to populate the recordsets into arrays and compare the arrays instead

help appreciated

Comment: What are the Stars (*) at the beginning and at end? and Doesn't looks like a congested code?

Comment: sorry stars are not in actual code. i've left some of the code out.

Answer (score 0):

Use MYSQL JOIN for retrieving the results.

Refer this one for JOINS..

http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

Answer (score 0):

You should use MYSQL Joins to accomplish this. If you only want to show items that are in both:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_items
     INNER JOIN tbl_itemsLeft 
     ON tbl_items.ItemID=tbl_itemsLeft.ItemID
```

If you want to view all items from tbl_items and see any that match or do not match with tbl_itemsLeft then you can do a LEFT JOIN and anything that has tbl_itemsLeft IS NULL will be records that do not have a match in the tbl_itemsLeft table.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_items 
     LEFT JOIN tbl_itemsLeft 
     ON tbl_items.ItemID=tbl_itemsLeft.ItemID
```

Another tip is that you should not use mysql api functions in php. These are deprecated functions as of PHP 5.5.0 and your code will no longer work after future php upgrades. I would recommend you look at running your queries using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: its not that i only want to show itemsleft the goal is to list all items in an html table and highlight using a different colour the ones that are left. hence the itemPresent variable will be used when drawing the table